# Laravel : pass parameters on function on route

Tags: laravel, routes

How do you pass parameters on a function in routes.php

```
Route::get('/{order}', array("as" => "ordered", "uses" => 'HomeController@ordered'), function() {
            Session::put('order',$order')
        });
```

Doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4):

How about like this:

```
<?php
Route::get('/{order}', array("as" => "ordered", "uses" => 'HomeController@ordered'), function() use ($order) {
        Session::put('order',$order')
    });
```

More detailed examples can be found here [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) **Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope**

What is important here is to notice the **use** keyword. It lets you pass variables defined outside of your anonymous function.

**Edit**

My bad, its seems I misunderstood. Try it this way:

```
<?php
Route::get('/{order}', array("as" => "ordered", "uses" => 'HomeController@ordered'), function($order) {
    Session::put('order',$order')
});
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. i need to get the value of {order} and use it on the function.

Answer (score 2):

Just Change to the following..........

```
Route::get('/{order}','HomeController@ordered');
```

And On HomeController............

```
  public function ordered($order){
       ///////////////////your code here, use $order here
    });
```

Comment: that's what I'm using right now, I just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: It's possible if u shift your function to the controller and keep your route like Route::get('/{order}', array("as" => "ordered", "uses" => 'HomeController@ordered'));

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this
Route:

```
Route::get('/{order}','HomeController@ordered');
```

Controller:
method of HomeController-

```
function ordered($order) {

}
```

you can also pass more than one parameters

Route:

```
Route::get('/{order}/{id}','HomeController@ordered');
```

Controller:

```
function ordered($order,$id) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better (5 years) late than never:

```
Route::get('/{order}', array("as" => "ordered", "uses" => 'HomeController@ordered'), function() {
            Session::put('order', request()->route('order'));
        });
```